# Why am I getting an exit status of 1?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, exit, spyder

So, I am writing this code to analyze this video but I am facing this issue when I try to run it in Spyder, Anaconda:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import math

##Converts the given file into a series of images
def Video_to_Image_Converter(fileName):
    res1 = call("ffmpeg -i " + fileName + " -vf fps=1 frame-%d.jpg", shell=True)
    print(res1)
    result = subprocess.Popen('ffprobe -i '+ fileName +' -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    output = result.communicate()
    print(output)
    #return math.ceil(float(output[0])) + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    videoLength = Video_to_Image_Converter('sampleVideo.wmv')
    print(videoLength)
```

So, this code worked fine in iPython but I started having issues when trying to use Spyder. res1 should have an exit status of 0 if everything went well but it is 1. However, I do not know what went wrong. All it says when running subprocess.check_output on call is:

```
Command 'ffmpeg -i sampleVideo.wmv -vf fps=1 frame-%d.jpg' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Please help.

Comment: Try running the command and capturing `stderr` to see the error message.

Comment: BTW, this code is dangerous -- someone who could give you a video file with an arbitrary name could thus cause chosen code to be run on your machine. Consider what happens if you call this for every file in an uploads directory that contains `$(rm -rf ~).mkv`. Much, **much** safer to take out the `shell=True` and make it `['ffmpeg', '-i', fileName, '-vf', 'fps=1', 'frame-%d.jpg']`; that'll also fix simpler cases, like filenames with spaces.

Comment: BTW, to adjust the latter command to work without a shell, it would be `['ffprobe', '-i', fileName, '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-v', 'quiet', '-of', 'csv=p=0']` -- note that the quotes around `p=0` are gone. This is because in the original shell code those were *syntactic* quotes, not *literal* ones, so they weren't actually passed to `ffprobe` but were instead taken out by the shell during the [quote removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quote-Removal.html) stage of [parsing](http://stuff.lhunath.com/parser.png).

Comment: @Barmar How do I see that?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If I remove "shell=True", then I always get "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified." I understand it is bad but it seems like it runs at least.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` should do it

Comment: That "file not found" error is presumably the reason it's not working in the first place. You probably need to give a full pathname to the file, because it's not in the current directory.

Comment: @Barmar The path is in the current directory though. And I tried the stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, it does not change anything in the output. Since I am using Spyder, do I have to install ffmpeg a different way? I know Spyder has its own python so can it maybe not find ffmpeg?

Comment: Maybe. Try using the full pathname to the ffmpeg command.

Comment: @Akaisteph7, ...ahh, **Windows**. The rules are different there. (Wildly different -- on UNIX, everything gets converted to an array, so using a string is adding a bunch of extra complexity; on Windows, everything gets converted to a string, so using an array is depending on other code to do the conversion). Going forward, you might want to include the platform in the question proper.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured the problem. I installed ffmpeg on my computer but for some reason Anaconda does not seem to use the environment variables to look for the programs it should run. It seems Anaconda has its own set of installed programs and I had to install it through conda using
    "conda install -c menpo ffmpeg"  (from https://anaconda.org/menpo/ffmpeg).